# OnTouchListener JAVA remove qualifier using Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

This is what I'm trying to do. I have 3 text boxes, a submit button and image on the screen. I want the image to go away if any of the text boxes are touched to input data for the login credentials. The reason is that the soft keyboard pushes the image up into the text boxes when the user tries to input anything. I tried the setOnClickListener but it appears that takes two clicks into the field using the AVD. So I'm trying to use OnTouchListener and it's not going well.

It is asking me to remove the qualifier because of an 'expected Class or package'. It wants to remove the login from this line of code.

```
login.OnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener(){
```

It happens with the other two text boxes which are name 'phone' and 'password'.

Next, if I remove the qualifier then it complains about a Method call expected and wants to do an insert which changes the code to this.

```
new View.OnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
```

Then it complains about 'OnTouchListener' is abstract; cannot be instantiated' and wants to implement a method, which gives an error at the end about an expected ). When this is added the whole cycle starts over with the same error messages.

Here's the pieces that I believe are important.

The import statement

```
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
```

The variables that I'm using for the OnTouchListner.

```
final EditText phone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.phone1);
final EditText login = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.uname);
final EditText pass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
```

The onTouchListener that I need so I can make the image invisible and not overlap the text box input.

```
login.OnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener(){
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                    image.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method signature you're looking for is `login.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() { ... }`

Comment: Charles - thank you!!!! That worked. Not sure why I missed that. Probably because I'm new to Java. But thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

The reason this is happening is because OnTouchListener is a class, not a method.

The correct way to add an OnTouchListener is to call

```
setOnTouchListener( listener )
```

So, for your code,

```
login.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener(){
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                    image.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Comment: Psychrom - thank you for the explanation. I'm still learning Java.

Comment: Not a problem, that's what we're all here for. :)